# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new...ProgressBarProcess.Value = 1 not showing?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

This is for Windows 10, Windows Application WPF .NET framework 4.7.2

I have code from an older windows form project (vs 2017 community) for a ProgressBar that worked fine (Windows Forms project). I have a wpf windows project now that works fine but I wanted to add a progress bar to the two buttons (Proccess and Insert buttons) click event because they take several seconds to complete and I want to see some progress. This project is for me only and it always runs inside visual studio (community 2019). I copied the old code to the new project but the progressbar does not show up or show progress. The code is in the buttonclick event in the old project as in the new one but no luck....I maybe missing something from the old project but I don't see what. I know about the "can not modify the UI from the calling thread" but I thought I used a different thread with Task.Factory.StartNew. There are a lot of posts/threads here for Dispatcher.BeginInvoke but I couldn't find one similar to mine ... one of them said  that this approach was the wrong way to do it. I don't do MVVM stuff. I don't do windows programming C# very often so don't assume that I know what I'm doing....LOL. Any help to show the progressbar would be appreciated. A pointer on how to do it "right" also appreciated.Thanks. Here is the code for one of the buttons (ProcessButton_Click) its progressbar is named "ProgressBarProcess":

```
 private void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (targetBOMTextBox.Text.Length != 11)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Target BOM part number missing or incorrect format.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessButtonFunction());
    }

 private void ProcessButtonFunction()
        {
            ProgressBarProcess.Minimum = 1;
            ProgressBarProcess.Maximum = 5;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }));

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 1; }));
            fillExcelLists();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 2; }));
            convertTofloatList();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 3; }));
            splitDesignatorList();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 4; }));
            fillRecordsList();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 5; }));

            insertButton.IsEnabled = true;
            clearButton.IsEnabled = true;


        }



private void fillExcelLists()
    {
        ExcelAccess ExcelAccessOBJ = new ExcelAccess();

        //get part numbers from excel column to GlobalData.excelPartNoList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(partNoComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(dataStartRowTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt16(dataEndRowTextBox.Text), GlobalData.excelPartNoList);

        //get quantities from excel column to GlobalData.excelQuantityList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(quantityComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(dataStartRowTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt16(dataEndRowTextBox.Text), GlobalData.excelQuantityList);
       
        //get designators from excel column to GlobalData.excelDesignatorList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(designatorsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt16(dataStartRowTextBox.Text), Convert.ToInt16(dataEndRowTextBox.Text), GlobalData.excelDesignatorList);

    }
 

 public class ExcelAccess
{
    public void ExcelReadColumn(string column, int rowStart, int rowEnd, List<String> saveData)
    {
        //set up excel stuff
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(GlobalData.excelFilenameAndPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range data_range;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);      //first sheet

        //Read column
        for (int i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++)
        {
            data_range = sheet.get_Range(column + i.ToString(), column + i.ToString());     //read part number from excel sheet

            //Convert cell value to string 
            string tempString = Convert.ToString(data_range.Cells.Value2);
            if (tempString != string.Empty)
            {
                saveData.Add(tempString);
            }
            
        }

        theWorkbook.Close();
        ExcelObj.Quit();

    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ProgressBarProcess.Minimum = 1` throw an `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: Using a breakpoint: No exceptions but it seems to hang at ProgressBarProcess.Minimum = 1 and ProgressBarProcess.Maximum = 5, so I commented them out, now it hangs at fillExcelLists(); It did show the progressbar though.

Comment: Every UIElement like ProgressBar should be accessed from the UI-thread only. So use the Dispatcher every time you access the ProgressBar, like you do it at setting the visibility. Thennstep in your `fillExcelLists` method to see where exactly it hangs.

Comment: @Rodo: How is `fillExcelLists` and the other methods implemented?

Comment: @mm8: I added the code for fillExcelLists() and the class. It seems to hung at the code line "ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(partNoComboBox..."

Comment: Have you enabled the debugger to break on all exceptions? You should go to the "Exception Settings" window (Ctrl+Alt+E) and ensure that at least all exceptions under the node "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" are enabled. It does not make any sense for the debugger to halt silently. Otherwise you would have to step into the ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn method.

Comment: @BionicCode: I did what you said. Now I see the exception. It seems to be the same when the code hangs: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: That was expected. To solve the problem, you should implement the solution provided by mm8. But you need to improve it in order to make it work. You must remove all references to a control from methods like fillExcelLists(). Then extract the required information before you start the Task and pass them to the fillExcelLists() method. You must do this for the other methods too (in case they access UI elements too).

Answer (score 0):

Stay on the dispatcher thread and await tasks that execute the long-running methods on background threads:

```
private async void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (targetBOMTextBox.Text.Length != 11)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Target BOM part number missing or incorrect format.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return;
    }

    ProgressBarProcess.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    ProgressBarProcess.Minimum = 1;
    ProgressBarProcess.Maximum = 5;
    ProgressBarProcess.Value = 1;
    await Task.Run(() => fillExcelLists());
    ProgressBarProcess.Value = 2;
    await Task.Run(() => convertTofloatList());
    ProgressBarProcess.Value = 3;
    await Task.Run(() => splitDesignatorList());
    ProgressBarProcess.Value = 4;
    await Task.Run(() => fillRecordsList());
    ProgressBarProcess.Value = 5;

    insertButton.IsEnabled = true;
    clearButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

No need to involve the dispatcher really.

Comment: I guess that introduces cross thread exceptions as fillExcelLists() accesses UI elements. You should collect the data from those elements and pass them as arguments to the fillExcelLists() (to remove the critical references from the method).

Comment: This almost works. The progressbar shows but it does not show "progress". At the end it just turns green at the same time the 
 insertButton shows enabled. I get no exceptions at all though. Oh yeah I forgot to say that I removed all the UI access from fillExcelLists(). It was the only one accessing the UI.

Comment: @Rodo: Did you really execute the long-running methods on background threads in tasks then? Or how fast are they? If you temporarily replace `fillExcelLists()` and the other methods with calls to `Thread.Sleep(2000)`, you should see the `ProgressBar` moving.

Comment: @mm8: I replaced the call to fillExcelLists() with its content (as shown in my answer) using your code to see if it would show progress. It didn't. So I tried Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessButtonFunction()); and it showed progress. So I went with the Task.Factory.StartNew... I would have preferred your code because it is simpler but I couldn't get it to work. I may try again later but I'm busy doing other stuff right now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I end up doing and works. I wanna thanks everyone for their help. The main issue I had seems to be that I was accessing UI from where I wasn't supposed to. Also ProgressBarProcess.Minimum and ProgressBarProcess.Maximum don't seem to work as I read ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar?view=netframework-4.7.2)), probably something I missed. Thanks again:

```
 private void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (targetBOMTextBox.Text.Length == 11)
        {
            GlobalData.TargetBOMpartNo = targetBOMTextBox.Text;

            GlobalData.partNoColumn = partNoComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            GlobalData.quantityColumn = quantityComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            GlobalData.designatorColumn = designatorsComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            GlobalData.dataRowStart = Convert.ToInt16(dataStartRowTextBox.Text);
            GlobalData.dataRowEnd = Convert.ToInt16(dataEndRowTextBox.Text);

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Target BOM part number missing or incorrect format.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }

        ProcessButton.IsEnabled = false;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessButtonFunction());
      
    }

 private void ProcessButtonFunction()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }));

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 10; }));
        fillExcelLists();
        convertTofloatList();
        splitDesignatorList();
        fillRecordsList();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 100; }));

        //insertButton.IsEnabled = true;    //this generates an exception do it like below
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { insertButton.IsEnabled = true; }));

        //clearButton.IsEnabled = true;  //this generates an exception do it like below
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { clearButton.IsEnabled = true; }));

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }));

    }

 private void fillExcelLists()
    {
        ExcelAccess ExcelAccessOBJ = new ExcelAccess();

        //get part numbers from excel column to GlobalData.excelPartNoList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(GlobalData.partNoColumn, GlobalData.dataRowStart, GlobalData.dataRowEnd, GlobalData.excelPartNoList);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 30; }));
        
        //get quantities from excel column to GlobalData.excelQuantityList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(GlobalData.quantityColumn, GlobalData.dataRowStart, GlobalData.dataRowEnd, GlobalData.excelQuantityList);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 60; }));

        //get designators from excel column to GlobalData.excelDesignatorList
        ExcelAccessOBJ.ExcelReadColumn(GlobalData.designatorColumn, GlobalData.dataRowStart, GlobalData.dataRowEnd, GlobalData.excelDesignatorList);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { ProgressBarProcess.Value = 90; }));

    }
```